# dockerd failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported

Tags: macos, docker

I've been running a few containers (approximately a dozen) for awhile now. I've approached whatever the hard limit is on container/image sizes in the past, and had to clean these up to keep it from barfing all over everything, and recently the same has happened again.

I have identified several containers and images I can safely remove to reduce its footprint. But just as I was getting ready to do so, Docker crashed on me. And when I attempt to restart it, it crashes with the error message:

```
Fatal Error
Docker daemon failed to start
[timestamp] dockerd failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
```

Thus, I can't use any of the command-line tools to remove these images/containers.

As there are running containers that I don't dare delete at this point, this makes it a little difficult to resolve. Is there a way to start Docker (on the mac) that doesn't actually start any of the containers so that maybe I can avoid this error?

Is the error message even related to my problem? I'm on Docker 2.3.0.4 if it matters.

Answer (score 5):

You could switch to overlay2 driver instead of graph driver

You can follow the document below to switch

https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/

Comment: That seems reasonable to me... but will it force me to ditch my existing containers?

Comment: Yes, you have to save your images and run all containers over again

Comment: With Docker all but dead on my machine, it does not seem possible to migrate either containers or their volumes off the machine.